# Catch onKeyDown In separate Thread

Tags: java, android, onkeydown

I'm catching a onKeyDown event in an Activity, but, how could I do a class to call that could replace event on the "onKeyDown" for all my Activities?

```
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == 6 || keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) { 
  //Do Something
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The title of the question and the description are a bit inconsistent, what has a separate thread to do with a class that should handle onKeyDown logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base class that extends Activity and then have all your classes extend that.  In the base class handle onKeyDown().

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == 6 || keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) { 
            // Do Something fancy
        }
    // ...
}

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    // ...
}
```